# Google Calendar API get an event

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to get an event from google calendar, based on it's ID and to update some data on it.

```
$client = $this->getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();
```

The code from above is for all events and works.

```
$client = $this->getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendar = $service->calendarList->get($calendarId);
```

The code from above is for a single event and I get an error on request. From what I saw I need a second param like `$optParams` , but I am not sure what value to give to this param.

[URL for google doc.](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get)

**Error message.**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
 in ..\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:123
Stack trace:
#0 ..\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(98): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 ..\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176): Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 ..\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(61): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#3 C:\xampp\sites\calmnest\wp-content\plugins\nrc- in ..\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 123
```

Comment: _And I get an error_ So what error do you get?

Comment: calendarList.get has nothing to do with getting a single event. Calendarlist is the list on the bottom left hand side of the UI there is no guarantee that the calendar list will be populated, if you want a calendar there you should insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

You are getting an error because you are not using the correct method

### How to update an event

1. [Get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) the event
2. Modify the event
3. [Update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) the event

Both methods use two query parameters: `calendarId` and `eventId`:

- `calendarId`: you can write `primary` or you `gmail` account. In order to see all available calendars in your account you can list them with: [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)
- `eventId`: the `id` of the event that you want to update. You can list all the available events in a particular calendar with: [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

### Code

```
$calendarId = 'primary';
$eventId = 'eventId'; 

// Get Event
$event = $service->events->get($calendarId, $eventId); 

// Modify Event
$event->setSummary('New title');
$event->setDescription('New describtion');

// Update Event
$updatedEvent = $service->events->update($calendarId, $eventId, $event);
```

Comment: Thank you! Also at the beginning I had to write $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS); . Initially I had CALENDAR.